# Do I need an ESTA or transit visa?

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, transit-visas

I am traveling from the UK to Mexico via USA, do I need to apply for a visa waiver program (ESTA)

Comment: At the very least, you'll need to tell us your nationality first.

Answer (score 1):

If your nationality is eligible for the Visa Waiver Program (a UK passport holder would be) you'll need to apply for the ESTA before you leave.  Otherwise, unless you are Canadian or Bermudan, you'll need a valid US visa.

If you're relying on the VWP and don't apply you'll likely be denied boarding to the US-bound flight.